# JSSOR Slider - Can the social icons be moved above the image while keeping them responsive?

Tags: hyperlink, slider, jssor

Jssor slider:
Is it possible to move the social links div above the image, while keeping it responsive with the image. The demos have the social bar on top of the image.  I have done this & it appears to work correctly in all current browsers, with the exception of resizing issue only in IE. Can it be done?

Comment: To clarify:  I can get the social icon to show, but when the browser is resized to a smaller size, the page resizes responsively, however, a horizontal scrollbar appears. When scrolling horizontallty to the right side of the resized browser, there is only a blank screen on the right side.  This only occurs in IE. Chrome, Opera & Firefox perform correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it doesn't display in ie 8;
Please set z-index 10 for share button navigator as follows,

```
<div u="any" style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 6px; right: 16px; width: 280px; height: 40px; z-index: 10;">
```